# how to create an array element in form - zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want to create the following element :

```
<input type="file" name="file[]">
```

I have tried the following code in     myproject/module/Member/src/Member/Form/EditForm.php     :

```
$this->add(array(
            'name' => 'file',
            'type'  => 'file',
            'attributes' => array(                
                'class' => 'form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12',                
                'id' => 'file',                
            ),'options' => array(
                'multiple'=>TRUE
            ),
        ));
```

and

```
$this->add(array(
            'name' => 'file[]',
            'type'  => 'file',
            'attributes' => array(                
                'class' => 'form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12',                
                'id' => 'file',                
            ),'options' => array(
                'multiple'=>TRUE
            ),
        ));
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For file upload [Zend Framework 2 has a special `FileInput` class](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.input-filter.file-input.html#file-upload-input).

It is important to use this class because it also does other important things like [validation before filtering](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-inputfilter/blob/master/src/FileInput.php#L143). There are also [special filters like the `File\RenameUpload`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.filter.file.rename-upload.html#renameupload) that renames the upload for you.

Considering that `$this` is your `InputFilter` instance the code could look like this:

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'file',
    'required' => true,
    'allow_empty' => false,
    'filters' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'File\RenameUpload',
            'options' => array(
                'target' => 'upload',
                'randomize' => true,
                'overwrite' => true
            )
        )
    ),
    'validators' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'FileSize',
            'options' => array(
                'max' => 10 * 1024 * 1024 // 10MB
            )
        )
    ),
    // IMPORTANT: this will make sure you get the `FileInput` class
    'type' => 'Zend\InputFilter\FileInput'
);
```

To attach file element to a form:

```
// File Input
$file = new Element\File('file');
$file->setLabel('My file upload')
     ->setAttribute('id', 'file');
$this->add($file);
```

Check [the documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.file-upload.html) for more information on file upload.
Or check [the documentation here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.file-upload.html#file-post-redirect-get-plugin) on how to make an upload form

Comment: thanks for your reply.
I tried your code but got error :

An error occurred
An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
Additional information:
Zend\Form\Exception\InvalidElementException

File:
    /var/www/html/actifiti/admin/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Form/FormElementManager.php:121
Message:
    Plugin of type Zend\InputFilter\FileInput is invalid; must implement Zend\Form\ElementInterface

Comment: @ErFaiyazAlam `$this` is an `InputFilter` class in this case. Try to add to your input filter instance instead of your form.

Comment: @ErFaiyazAlam I edited my answer and added more links and examples. There is a lot of documentation on file upload.